# Using javascript/jquery to submit a form upon the loading of a page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I wrote an array to pass variables in the GET to a search page. The search page only has 4 fields but I'm only passing the most important variables, first name and last. Here is the array:

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='" . matry::base_to('test/trace', array('first'=>$patient->first , 'last' =>$patient->last)) . "'><ul class='controls'>
                    <li id='check_orders'><`span class='symbols'>L</span><span class='label'>Skip Trace</span></li>

                </ul></a></td>";?>
```

When the page loads i'm just echoing the _GET to pre populate the first and last input fields on that page..

What I'm looking for is a script that will execute the search with the first and last name fields populated as that page loads automatically. Additionally, when the search is executed it's populating in an iframe. (forgot about that part)~!

I tried using:

```
<script>document.getElementById('stack').submit();</script>

 <form action='http://xxxx.yyyyyyy.com/stuffhere' name='es' target="my_iframe" id="stack">
```

with no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<script>` is running before the `<form>` exists.

Move the `<script>` below the `<form>`.

Comment: damn.. stupid noob mistake! I moved it down and it worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the submit function before the form is even loaded on the page.

Place the script tag after the closing form tag or call submit on document ready or window onload.

```
<form id-"stack">
  ... form fields...
</form>
<script>document.getElementById('stack').submit();</script>
```

or

```
<script>$(function(){$('#stack').submit();})</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, been using this on a redirect page for a while. This of course needs to be below the from so it is run after the browser process the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send(o)
    {
        var f = document.getElementById("theForm");
        f.submit();
    }
    send();
</script>
```

Comment: That won't make a difference.

Comment: And why declare a function which is just called immediately? This single line will do the exact same thing is and is far simpler: `document.getElementById("theForm").submit()`

Comment: With the function you can have something else call it if needed, I have for example an anchor that says please click here if your browser didn't redirect.

Comment: @MatthewNie True, but that should never fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form when the page loads you should change your code to this:

```
<script>window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('stack').submit(); }</script>
```

However this will redirect the user (as if they have clicked a form submit button). To avoid this you will need to use AJAX (I recommend using jQuery to do this). See example below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var form_data = $("#form_id").serialize();
    var form_url = $("#form_id").attr("action");
    var form_method = $("#form_id").attr("method").toUpperCase();

    $.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false       
    });    

 });
```

See [this page](http://me.cloudcell.co.uk/jquery-ajax-form-submit) for more info on using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Please imagine this simple example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function body_onload() {
            var form = document.getElementById('theform');
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="body_onload()">
    <form id="theform" action="action.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="query" id="query" value="foo" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

It will submit the form after the page has loaded.

But are you really searching for a non AJAX solution?